# What is the name of the spell or effect that prevents resurrection?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, product-identification

I remember seeing a spell (or perhaps a weapon enhancement?) that prevents the target from being resurrected if killed in DnD 3.5.

However, I don't remember the spell name, nor its source, so any pointer is welcome. I think it was official material, so no third party suggestion in the answers, please.

I am talking of permanent prevention of resurrection so *not* stuff like Trap the soul :)

Answer (score 14):

I can't neglect the [*bag of devouring*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/cursedItems.htm#bagofDevouring), which if it eats a creature, the creature only has a 50% chance of being able to be brought back from the dead. Besides that, here are some spells and weapons.

### Spells that prevent a creature from being brought back from the dead

- The 6th-level Clr and 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell ***barghest's feast*** [necro] (*Spell Compendium* 24) causes 1 touched corpse to check SR and make a Willpower saving throw. Failure means a 50% chance that *wish*, *miracle*, and *true resurrection* effects can't bring back the dead. One assumes that *also* incapable of bringing back the dead creature are lesser, similar effects (e.g. *raise dead*, *reincarnation*), but ask the DM. *Note:* If the creature's not dead but helpless save yourself the 5,000 gp material component, [call](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/planarBindingLesser.htm) a [barghest](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/barghest.htm), and offer it a snack. It'll probably thank *you*.
- The 9th-level Clr and Sor/Wiz spell ***necrotic termination*** [necro] (*Libris Mortis* 69) has the caster pay 1,000 XP and causes 1 creature possessing a necrotic cyst within medium range to make a Fortitude saving throw. Failure means its cyst devours its soul, killing the creature forever, and making a free-willed undead from the target's corpse. Success means the target is dealt 1d6 damage/caster level (maximum 25d6), half of which is vile damage.
- The 8th-level corrupt spell ***plague of nightmares*** [ench] (*Book of Vile Darkness* 100) causes 1 touched living creature to make a Fortitude saving throw upon awakening each day. Success ends the spell. Failure means the creature is dealt 1d4 points of Charisma damage; reducing the target's Charisma to 0 this way, presumably, kills the creature forever (according to the text the creature is dead "beyond even [the power of] a *true resurrection* spell"), but ask the DM.

### Weapons that prevent a creature from being brought back from the dead

- A weapon made from the special material **thinaun** (*Complete Warrior* 136-7) (+10,000, +15,000, or +20,000 gp for a light, 1-handed, or 2-handed weapon; 0 lbs.) traps within it the soul of the last creature killed while touching the weapon (usually touched forcibly by the stabby end, but possibly an unlucky wielder), preventing anyone but the weapon's holder from bringing the creature back from the dead. *Note:* Sadly, ammunition isn't an option.
- The melee weapon special ability ***Keeper's fang*** (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 266) (+4 bonus) sends the souls of creatures killed with it to the Keeper's domain—a sort of competitor to actual hell—, where the Keeper prevents the creatures from returning from the dead except through DM fiat. *Note:* Carrying such a weapon means just about everyone in Eberron who matters thinks you're a jerk.

Answer (score 6):

The spell Necrotic Termination (Libris Mortis) does what you ask:

> If the subject fails her saving throw, the cyst expands beyond control, killing the subject and digesting her soul. Raise dead, resurrection, true resurrection, wish, and miracle cannot return life to the subject once her soul is digested— she is gone forever.

Barghest's feast gives 50% odds of "no mortal magic able to be used to return the corpse" and is easier to do on a fallen foe.

A Thinaun weapon traps the soul in it, and is cheap. Disposing of the weapon somewhere impossible is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score -1):

There are three ways.

1. You can disintegrate the victim and scatter the ashes. If no part of the original creature can be found, they can't be resurrected. However, True Resurrection is harder to block.
2. If you can command undead, you can cause your target to be aged to death. Any undead with Corrupting Touch should do. (This includes [ghosts](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=006680642033474972217%3A6zo0hx_wle8&q=ghost#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=ghost%20corrupting%20touch&gsc.sort=&gsc.ref=more%3Abestiary), [Spectral Trolls](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/spectral-troll-cr-1-tohc), et. al.) Once a person dies of old age, they can't be resurrected.
3. There is also the [Scepter of Ages](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/artifacts/major-artifacts/scepter-of-ages) which can be used to supernaturally age a victim. Tho the GM may be wary of giving this item to players do to temporal paradox. (see link)

Comment: -1: The stuff that you suggest here (other than scattering the ashes) all references Pathfinder sources. This question is a 3.5 question, so Pathfinder sources don't apply.